# Magento 2: available field types in system.xml

Tags: magento2, system-configuration

What are available values for field types in `etc/system.xml` configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="...">
            <group id="...">
                <field id="..." type="???">
                    ...
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Magento 2 system configuration **provides below fields type**.

```
checkbox,
checkboxes,
column,
date,
editablemultiselect,
editor,
fieldset,
file,
gallery,
hidden,
image,
imagefile,
label,
link,
multiline,
multiselect,
note,
obscure,
password,
radio,
radios,
reset,
select,
submit,
text,
textarea,
time
```

Comment: label does not work

Comment: any idea on how to make Yes/NO button with green/gray color ?

Comment: @ZeeshanKhuwaja and future people, this doesn't link to the Q but you want to append <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model> to your field

Answer (score 19):

Looking at the file [`/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Form/Element/Factory.php`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Form/Element/Factory.php) (sources on Github, for Magento 2.2 & 2.3), one can find the following default list of elements, as specified by Amit in [his answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155870/55289):

```
// Factory.php, lines 26-55
protected $_standardTypes = [
    'button',
    'checkbox',
    'checkboxes',
    'column',
    'date',
    'editablemultiselect',
    'editor',
    'fieldset',
    'file',
    'gallery',
    'hidden',
    'image',
    'imagefile',
    'label',
    'link',
    'multiline',
    'multiselect',
    'note',
    'obscure',
    'password',
    'radio',
    'radios',
    'reset',
    'select',
    'submit',
    'text',
    'textarea',
    'time',
];
```

If Composer was used to install Magento, the data may also be found in `/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Factory.php`, as mentioned in Mohit's comment below.

Comment: My apologies for adding a new answer rather than commenting on Amit's. As of posting this answer I do not have enough reputation to comment on others' answers.

Comment: I think you have completed Amit's answer by adding factory file details. Upvoted for this.

Comment: But my Magento 2.2.3 does not have such path. I could find Factory.php file at **`/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Factory.php`** path.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora You are correct! I think that the differing file paths have to do with how Magento was installed: cloning from Git seems to use `/lib/internal`, while Composer is known to create the `/vendor` folder. I will update the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Can any one can add/explain field types with sorce models, Like yesno has source model Magento/config/model/config/source/yesno

Answer (score 1):

[Magento 2 docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-systemxml.html#field-type-reference).

`text`              Standard, single row text field

`textarea`          Text block

`select`            Normal dropdown, may need a custom source_model. Also used for Yes/No selections. See Magento\Search\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Engine for an example.

`multiselect`       Like select but multiple options are valid.

`button`            A button that triggers an immediate event. Requires custom front-end model to define the button text and the action. See Magento\ScheduledImportExport\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Clean for an example.

`obscure`           A text field with the value encrypted and displayed as ****. Changing the type using “Inspect Element” in the browser does not reveal the value.

`password`          Like obscure except that the hidden value is not encrypted, and forcibly changing the type using “Inspect Element” in the browser does reveal the value.

`file`              Allows a file to be uploaded for processing.

`label`             Displays a label instead of an editable field. Use this type when a field is editable only on specific scopes, for example Store View level only.

`time`              Control to set time using three dropdowns–Hour, minute and second.

`allowspecific`     A multiselect list of specific countries. Requires a source_model such as Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries

`image`             Allows an image to be uploaded.

`note`              Allows an informational note to be added to the page. This type requires a frontend_model to render the note.